# colorear celdas si matchean con un string

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Como va comunidad! estoy tratando de hacer algo que en principio hablando sin saber deberia ser muy simple pero sinceramente no encuentro el como, veo soluciones pero que son un tanto complejas y estoy tratando de buscar algo bien simple, tengo un dataframe donde algunas celdas dicen "free" quiero que si en la celda(siempre la misma columna) dice "free" se coloree de verde por ejemplo.

en principio este es mi script:

```
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from datetime import datetime
import re
from pathlib import Path
import os
import pandas as pd

hora = datetime.now()
dia = hora.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
fecha = hora.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H-%M-%S")
ruta = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos\ROUTER - show interfaces description pipe include Gi0-3-4-3.txt")
ruta2 = Path("E:\Python\Visual Studio Code Proyects\M2M Real\Archivos\\")

with open(ruta, "r") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

with open(ruta, "w") as fw:
    for line in lines:
        if not re.match("-{5}|\s+|([A-Za-z0-9]+( [A-Za-z0-9]+)+)", line):
            fw.write(line)

csv_name2 = f'{ruta2}\{ruta.stem}.csv'

df = pd.read_fwf(ruta)

df["Description"] = (df.iloc[:, 3:].fillna("").astype(str).apply(" ".join, axis=1).str.strip())

df = df.iloc[:, :4]

df = df.drop(columns = ["Status", "Protocol"])

df.Interface = df.Interface.str.extract('Gi0/3/4/3\.(\d+)')
df = df[df.Interface.notnull()].reset_index()
print(df)
df = df.drop(["index"], axis=1)

print(df)

df['Interface'] = df['Interface'].astype(int)

df = df.set_index('Interface').reindex(range(1,3580)).fillna('free').reset_index()

print(df)

df = df.to_csv(csv_name2, index=False, sep=";")
```

El arachivo de origen se ve asi:

```
Interface          Status      Protocol    Description
Gi0/3/4/3          up          up          ENLACE A Router2
Gi0/3/4/3.401      up          up          Frontera Cliente A
Gi0/3/4/3.402      up          up          Frontera Cliente B
Gi0/3/4/3.403      up          up          Frontera Cliente C
```

y luego de ser iterado y de forma resumida ya que tiene 3500 lineas se ve asi:

```
Interface   Description
395         free
396         free
397         free
398         free
399         free
400         free
401         Frontera Cliente A
402         Frontera Cliente B
403         Frontera Cliente C
404         Frontera Cliente D
```

Como les comentaba necesito q vaya iterando por las celdas de la columna "descripcion" y si matchea con "free" lo pinte de color verde.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero que todo no puedes colorear un archivo .csv ya que el mismo es solo texto

Para colorear las celdas en base a un condición puedes utilizar el método `.style.applymap()` al cual le pasas una función que valida la condición y retorna una cadena con el estilo a aplicar

Te dejo por acá la documentación para que la revises mas a detalle [Style Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html)

Ejemplo:

```
def is_free(valor):
    color = 'green' if valor == "free"  else 'white'
    return 'background-color: %s' % color
```

y luego aplicas el estilo a tu `dataframe` y lo exportas, en este caso a un archivo de excel para poder visualizar el estilo aplicado

```
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")
df.style.applymap(is_free).to_excel("result.xlsx", index=False)
```

y el resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Como estas GmrYael? muchisimas gracias, me acabas de explicar algo mas basico aun que no lo tenia en claro y es q los archivos csv son texto y no es posible aplicarle estilos, asi q primero q nada gracias por eso.

segundo, muchas gracias!! funciono! solo como aclaracion que debi agregar es el **sep=";"**en el read_csv

    df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", **sep=";"**)

Comment: Que bueno que haya sido útil mi respuesta, no agregue el separador ya que yo utilice solo un archivo de ejemplo el cual ajustaste a tu código!! 
Solo queda que marques la respuesta como aceptada! Saludos